# How to get first row of each group without using window functions Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get first row  of  each group with all attributes without using window functions like row_number etc.
Example Data is:

```
id amount
1   100
1   200
2   150 
2   300
2   250
3   400
```

What I want as a result:

```
id amount 
1  200
2  300
3  400
```

Comment: First row and biggest amount are different things. For your sample data they would be the same and you may aggregate as was answered. But if you need the first rows with all their attributes, then please describe why you want to avoid window functions

Comment: Sorry I couldn't describe it clearly . I want to get first rows with all their attributes without using window functions because of our ETL process

Answer (score 3):

No need for a window function:

```
SELECT id, MAX( amount ) AS amount
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
```